# Why is the operatornorm not a weak* continuous map?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence

> Let $X$ be a normed space and consider $$||\cdot ||:X^*\rightarrow \Bbb{R};~~f\mapsto ||f||$$ Then in a lecture side note I read that $||\cdot||$ is not weak* continuous.

As I understood it, we say $||\cdot||$ is weak* continuous **iff** for all $f_n\stackrel{\text{weak*}}{\longrightarrow}f$ implies $||f_n||\rightarrow ||f||$ **iff** for all $x\in X$, $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ implies $||f_n||\rightarrow ||f||$ where the second iff statement comes from the definition of weak* convergence.

> Now first I want to ask if this is true what I wrote till this point.

If yes wouldn't this mean that we ned to find $f_n$ such that for all $x\in X$ , $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ but $||f_n||\not \rightarrow ||f||$?
I don't see why such an $f_n$ should exist. Could maybe someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

If $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$ then $e_n \to 0$ weakly and $\|e_n\|=1$ for all $n$. Now use the fact that $H^{*}$ can be identified with $H$ itself by Riesz Theorem (and weak becomes weak* under this identification).

Comment: sorry to my first question, are my iff statements correct?
Could you maybe explain why we see that $e_n\rightarrow 0$ weakly? Because in my opinion a net $x_\alpha\rightarrow x$ weakly iff for all $f\in X^*$, $f(x_\alpha)\rightarrow f(x)$, and I don't see why $f(e_n)\rightarrow f(0)$ for all $f$

Comment: There exists $y$ such that $f(x)\equiv \langle x, y \rangle$. $f(e_n)=\langle e_n, y \rangle \to 0$ because $\sum |\langle e_n, y \rangle|^{2}<\infty$. These are  basic facts about Hilbert spaces. @user123234

Comment: ah and since $f$ is linear this means that $f(e_n)\rightarrow f(0)$ so since this holds for all $f$ we say that $e_n\rightarrow 0$ weakly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @user123234

Comment: ah okey but now we use that $J_H: H\rightarrow H^*;~~~x\mapsto \langle \cdot ,x\rangle$ is bijective and norm preserving. But then does this mean that $\langle \cdot, e_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle \cdot, 0\rangle$ weak*?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This argument actually works in any reflexive Banach space. @user123234

Comment: But now $\langle \cdot, e_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle \cdot, 0\rangle$ weak* means that $\langle a, e_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle a, 0\rangle$ for all $a\in H$. Right?

But now could you help me how to proceed